Why is Hudgens lying in wait at Bracken's place when Exley has sex with her?
Approximately 90 minutes into L.A. Confidential, Ed Exley (Guy Pearce) visits Lynn Bracken (Kim Basinger) to find out why Pierce Morehouse Patchett (David Strathairn) has instructed her to carry on a romantic relationship with Bud White (Russel Crowe)1.
After some brief banter, Exley is overcome with lust, and the two go to bed. We then see that Sid Hudgens (Danny DeVito) is hiding in the other room, taking pictures of them to use for blackmail purposes. (This explains why Bracken doesn't resist Exley2).
At 1h45m, Dudley Smith (James Cromwell) and Bud interrogate Hudgens, who confesses that Patchett instructed Hudgens to take those photos.
However, nobody could have known that Exley was coming to Bracken's home. And it's around midnight (based on what Smith says to "Hollywood Jack" Vincennes (Kevin Spacey), who visits him at home while Exley interrogates Bracken). Prior to that point, Exley and Bracken have no involvement. Exley and Bracken are not disturbed, so, by implication, she and Hudgens could not have been waiting for another client.
Patchett operates several prostitutes as part of his pimping and blackmail operation, and there's only one Hudgens, so it seems like quite the coincidence that Hudgens would be at her house when Exley randomly decides to visit.
Why was Hudgens there with his camera at the only opportunity to capture the photos Dudley Smith needed to later manipulate Bud White?

 1. Truth: she's been seeing Bud by choice.
2. Although, when Bud confronts her later, she claims that she did it because she thought she was helping Bud.


Nobody could have known that Pierce was coming to Basinger's home.

Not quite...there is a line in the screenplay (that seems to have been cut from the movie) when Exley is speaking to Patchett with Vincennes which gives us a clue.
Just as they leave, Exley says to Patchett

EXLEY:
Anything else you want to add
before I talk to her?

Indeed, the first thing Exley does is decide to speak to Lynn.
After Exley and Vincennes leave Patchett we see him (Patchett) call Hudgeons so he clearly wants him to do something as later confirmed.
So, we can interpret this as there was a set-up between Patchett, Hudgeons and Lynn to catch whoever turned up at Lynn's although Exley was the most likely to, and Patchett instructed Hudgeons to race over to Lynns and get in place immediately in time for whoever to turn up and they got extremely lucky.
